# Haskell explicit forall with "missing" type parameter on lhs

Tags: haskell

I was reading the source code of [haxl-Haxl.Core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxl-0.4.0.1/docs/src/Haxl-Core-Types.html#BlockedFetch) I came upon the following piece of code

```
data BlockedFetch r = forall a. BlockedFetch (r a) (ResultVar a)
```

And realized that I don't fully understand the usage of `ExplicitForall`/`ExistentialQuantification`.

In what ways is the snippet above different from

```
data BlockedFetch r a = BlockedFetch (r a) (ResultVar a)
```

And why can I "omit" the type parameter on the lhs of the data declaration.

Comment: The two types are completely different. The former allows you to, for example, have a list of `BlockedFetch` values with *different* `a` types (i.e. the type `[BlockedFetch r]` is valid and does *not* mention `a`), while the latter cannot because the type would be `[BlockedFetch r a]` but now all the `a`s of the elements must match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the example from the code is an example of an existential quantification, and so is totally different from the final example in the question.

The first thing to note is that nowadays GADT notation is often preferred for this.  The type in GADT notation is:

```haskell
data BlockedFetch r where
    BlockedFetch :: r a -> ResultVar a -> BlockedFetch r
```

We can explicitly bind `a` as follows:

```haskell
data BlockedFetch r where
    BlockedFetch :: forall a. r a -> ResultVar a -> BlockedFetch r
```

This would be isomorphic to the following if we had free existential quantification:

```haskell
data BlockedFetch r where
    BlockedFetch :: (exists a. (r a, ResultVar a)) -> BlockedFetch r
```

This, combined with a desire not to introduce new keywords, is what led to the old ExistentialQuantification syntax.  The `BlockedFetch` data constructor has type

```haskell
BlockedFetch :: forall r a. r a -> ResultVar a -> BlockedFetch r
```

and this is what is trying to be communicated with the syntax:

```haskell
data BlockedFetch r = forall a. BlockedFetch (r a) (ResultVar a)
```

From this perspective the difference from having `BlockedFetch r a` is then the `a` would occur in the result of the data constructor type.  Schematically, `forall a. F a -> G` is logically equivalent to `(exists a. F a) -> G`, but it is clearly not the case that `forall a. F a -> G a` is equivalent to `(exists a. F a) -> G a` as the latter is not even well-scoped.

Returning to

```haskell
BlockedFetch :: forall r a. r a -> ResultVar a -> BlockedFetch r
```

if you don't understand existentials, but you do understand universal quantification, then you can understand what's going on in terms of that.  Here we see that someone *calling* `BlockedFetch`, i.e. building a value with the data constructor, is free to choose whichever type they want for `a`.  Someone *consuming*, i.e. pattern matching on, a value of type `BlockedFetch R` is essentially writing a function `forall a. R a -> ResultVar a -> X` and that function must work for *any* value of `a`, i.e. the person calling this function gets to choose `a` and this function must work with that choice.

Comment: The point about GADT notation is highly relevant to epsilonhalbe's question. The use of the `forall` keyword enabled by `ExistentialQuantification` is actually quite different from the one enabled by `RankNTypes`, which is a potential source of confusion. GADT notation makes this difference obvious.

Comment: `+1` on GADT syntax, I can't think of a case where existential quantification looks better with regular ADT syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that you can (and in fact this happens a little further in the code) make a list of type `[BlockedFetch request]` where individual `BlockedFetch` have different `a` types (which you could not do with `[BlockedFetch request a]` - the `a` here has to be the same for the whole list). The comment above the snippet of code explains this nicely:

```
-- We often want to collect together multiple requests, but they return
-- different types, and the type system wouldn't let us put them
-- together in a list because all the elements of the list must have the
-- same type. So we wrap up these types inside the 'BlockedFetch' type,
-- so that they all look the same and we can put them in a list.
--
-- When we unpack the 'BlockedFetch' and get the request and the 'ResultVar'
-- out, the type system knows that the result type of the request
-- matches the type parameter of the 'ResultVar', so it will let us take the
-- result of the request and store it in the 'ResultVar'.
```

Roughly what happens in Haxl is that you want to have a way of fetching a bunch of values of different types in parallel from some remote store. The way you do this is by making a bunch of `MVar` which will contain the values you plan on getting. Then, in your code, you freely use these variables. However, and `MVar` blocks until it is "filled".

However, to fill the `MVar`, you only need to keep a reference to the `MVar` and a way of filling it - so at the end of the day you don't even need to know what the type is of the stuff the `MVar` will contain. That is an existential type - there exists some type `a` which the `BlockedFetch` is going to try to fill, but it will vary for different `BlockedFetch`s.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler example:

```
data ShowBox = forall a. Show a => ShowBox a
```

Read it as

```
data ShowBox = whatever a. Show a => ShowBox a
```

and now it's clear that `ShowBox` can contain a value of any type as long as this type is an instance of `Show`. E.g.

```
ex :: [ShowBox]
ex = [ShowBox 'a', ShowBox (), ShowBox [1,2,3]]
```

So you can read

```
data BlockedFetch r = forall a. BlockedFetch (r a) (ResultVar a)
```

as "`BlockedFetch` contains an `r a` and `ResultVar a` for whatever `a`".